# Can we stop the for loop when app goes background

Tags: iphone, ios7

The for loop is running fetching the data(images and text) from array but when i press home screen button the loop still continues in background and lasts more than 5 seconds which is default time, it should not be more that that as i studied while googling. And when i press home button even then the app delegates respective method like appEnterBackground also called after completion of this loop containing method. So, is it possible to break the loop when the home button is pressed.
Please guide.

Comment: You could wrap your long running code in a thread and then stop it when the `appEnterBackground` method is invoked. However introducing a thread can introduce various issues, so proceed with care...

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to detect the entering into background, in addition to responding to the app delegate `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, you could alternatively register yourself as an observer of the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification (e.g., using the `addObserverForName` method of `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`).

Note, if you want to cancel your requests, you will want to ensure that (a) the requests are run asynchronously; and (b) they're cancelable. If you're targeting iOS 7 and later, you can accomplish this with `NSURLSession` (e.g., `dataTaskWithRequest` or `dataTaskWithURL` which return a `NSURLSessionDataTask` object, on which you can call the `cancel` method if and when desired). Then you can write a handler for the notification that cancels any pending requests.

If you really want to cancel the requests, you can do something like the above, but you alternatively could simply request additional time to complete the requests if the app happens to go into background while the requests are running. This way you get a few minutes to finish requests rather than just a few seconds. See *Executing Finite-Length Tasks* in [App Programming Guide for iOS: Background States](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Or, perhaps even better, you could add your tasks to a background `NSURLSession`. See the *Downloading Content in the Background* section of the aforementioned [App Programming Guide for iOS: Background States](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). This way the tasks will continue even after your app is suspended (or, if you app is terminated due to memory pressure). For more information, see WWDC 2013 video, [What's New in Foundation Networking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=705).

Comment: Please study question again, m not fetching data from background, my issue is data is in array already in the form of dictionary containing images and text data, want to break the for loop when entered in to background after pressing home button.

Comment: What is this `for` loop doing?  I assumed you were synchronously loading data (hence my discussion on how to move that off the main thread, thereby doing it asynchronously, and then have it either stop the loading process when the app entering background mode, or better, seamlessly continue when entering background mode). But if not loading data, what is you `for` loop doing? BTW, you _never_ should have a loop doing anything in the main thread that takes more than a few milliseconds.